# Can I create a circular buffer on Linux? (current code segfaults)

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, file-descriptor

Inspired by [this example](https://github.com/cmuratori/refterm/blob/main/refterm_example_source_buffer.c) for Windows. In short, they create a file handle (with `CreateFileMapping`) then create 2 different pointers to the same memory (`MapViewOfFileEx` or `MapViewOfFile3`)

So I tried to do the same thing with `shm_open`, `ftruncate` and `mmap`. I used `mmap` a few times in the past for memory and files but I never mixed it with `shm_open` or used `shm_open`.

My code fails on the second `mmap` with a segfault. I tried doing a syscall directly on both mmaps and it still segfaults :( How do I do this properly? The idea is I can do `memcpy(p+len-10, src, 20)` and have the first 10bytes of src be at the end of the memory and last 10 written to the start (hence circular)

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
    write(2, "Start\n", 6); //prints this
    int len = 1024*1024*2;
    int fd = shm_open("example", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
    assert(fd > 0); //ok
    int r1 = ftruncate(fd, len);
    assert(r1 == 0); //ok
    char*p = (char*)mmap(0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    assert((long long)p>0); //ok
    //Segfaults on next line
    char*p2 = (char*)mmap(p+len, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, fd, 0); //segfaults
    write(2, "Finish\n", 7); //doesn't print this
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux usually selects address space for mappings starting from a certain point and goes lower with each reservation. So your 2nd `mmap` call replaces one of previous file mappings (likely `libc.so`), which leads to `SIGSEGV` with `SEGV_ACCERR` - invalid access permissions. You are overwriting executable section of `libc.so` (that is being executed right now) with non-executable data.

Use `strace` to check what is going on inside:

```
$ strace ./a.out 
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm/example", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0777) = 3
ftruncate(3, 2097152)                   = 0
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f134c1bf000
mmap(0x7f134c3bf000, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0) = 0x7f134c3bf000
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7f134c4ccc37} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Compare addresses you are passing around with `/proc/$pid/maps` file and you will see what you are overwriting.

Your mistake was to assume `MAP_FIXED` can be used without reserving memory beforehand. To do this properly you need to:

- Reserve memory by calling `mmap` with `len * 2` size, `PROT_NONE` and `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE` (and without file)
- Use `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` to overwrite portions of that mapping with the content you need

Additionally, you should prefer using `memfd_create` instead of `shm_open` on Linux to avoid shared memory files from staying around. Unlinking them with `shm_unlink` doesn't help if your program crashes. This also gives you a file that is private to your program instance.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was strange that a system call would crash me and not give some kind of error. The next problem appears to be the value not mirroring. If I make both p and p2 `volatile char*` and write `p[123] = 12; p2[123] = 45;` then printf I get 12 for p and 45 for p2. `memfd_create` and `shm_open` both do this

Comment: @EricStotch You should use `MAP_SHARED` instead of `MAP_PRIVATE`. Right now you are getting copy-on-write behavior e.g. each of two mapping have their own view of data. Also if you use `shm_open`, with `MAP_SHARED` every instance of your program will share that data which is not what you probably expect. Using `memfd_create` is basically mandatory at this stage as it is the closest equivalent to `CreateFileMapping`

Comment: That completely works. Thank you. I tried writing 5 and 4 to the different pointers and was expecting the optimizer to make a mistake in O2. It correctly showed me the second value when I read from both pointers. Do I not need volatile? I'm a little worried the optimizer will insert a check to make sure the pointers are different and produce incorrect (but fast) code. Am I worrying to much or should I use `volatile`?

Comment: In general, yes, but it also depends on how you are working with the buffer. Compiler can only optimize accesses only when they are close to each other, so you can get away with not using `volatile` while getting better generated code. Not using volatile should be fine, for example, if you are only writing items on one side and reading on the other side.

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to call `mmap` again to gen new pointer. (You even must not to do it.) Just increment it.

The pointer `p2` will not point to the address *just after* the memory block allocated.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
    write(2, "Start\n", 6); //prints this
    int len = 1024*1024*2;
    int fd = shm_open("example", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
    assert(fd > 0); //ok
    int r1 = ftruncate(fd, len);
    assert(r1 == 0); //ok
    char*p = (char*)mmap(0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    assert((long long)p>0); //ok
    char*p2 = p+len;
    write(2, "Finish\n", 7); //doesn't print this
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to have create a circular buffer so if I write `p[len+1]`  it will write the change to `p[1]`. Or more realistically `memcpy(p+len-10, src, 20)` which would copy 10 bytes at the end and 10bytes back at the start

Comment: You can cast the buffer to an array of integers, structs etc. It is simply another memory area, but not allocated using `malloc` (even `malloc` can call `mmap` in its implementation). You now have array or, if you want, memory area starting at address `p` and ending at `p + len`. When you cast it (e.g. `int *shm_array = p`, `struct foo_struct *shm_array = p`, …), you get an ordinary (but disk/shm-backed) array with `len / sizeof(array type)` items.